# What happens when I restart my asic miner?

Tags: mining-pools, mining-hardware, asic

I'm new to mining bitcoin with asic miner.
My question is, what happens when I replug my miner?
I have connected it to a pool. And when I replug it, the pool is showing that I stoped mining.

Comment: What model of miner?  What pool?

Comment: It is new miner "AladdinMiner" (I think they work the same), and the pool is slushpool (If you know better pool pliz let me know).